# Why I can't open downloaded file on Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have a simple functionality in my application, user can download the file and then open it or share using any other installed application. Before android Q I hadn't any trouble with this, but with new privacy changes, I don't know how to do this correctly. 
I need to do the next two steps:

1. Download file, using DownloadManager, in the common device Downloads folder (**not in the application downloads folder**)
2. Open this file or share this file (using intent)

To download the file to common Downloads folder I use next code

```
val request = DownloadManager.Request(config.uri)
    .setTitle(title)
    .setDescription(config.description)
    .setNotificationVisibility(notificationVisibility)
    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "filename.pdf")
val downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

and after downloading done I getting downloaded file Uri like this

```
val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)
val fileUriStr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
val fileUri = Uri.parse(fileUriStr)
```

In the end, when user click on button "Open", I creating next intent

```
val mime = context.contentResolver.getType(fileUri)
val intent = Intent()
    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(uri, mime)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
```

All these solutions work properly until Android Q. On android Q after Intent start I see the dialog to chose target application, when I pick target application I get error that this application cant access the file (I use Adobe Reader as target application).

So, the question is how to do this operation correctly on Android 10?

P/S/ Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Probably related to the Privacy changes in Android 10
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage
And also upcoming Android 11 https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

Comment: Also, maybe this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#other-file-types

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem. I used `DownloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile()` instead of the `Uri` returned from query and the problem solved! I don't know what exactly causes the problem but I found that this solution doesn't work on lower versions. So I ended up with this line:

```
var fileUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(requestId) else Uri.parse(fileUriStr)
```

Also I get the mime type from here:

```
val mime = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE))
```

And it works on all versions.